# invalid operands to binary + (have 'float*'and'float*')

Tags: c

Hey I'm new here :D (i know this  have any relation with the questions )
every time i try to build my code this error apear :
invalid operands to binary + (have 'float*'and'float*') 
here is my code

```
void verser() {
    int j,i;
    long n,m;
    float *s;
    printf("saisir ton num de compte");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("saisir num de compte desti");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("saisir la valeur a verser");
    scanf("%i",&s);
    *s/=4.0;
    for (i=0; i<c; i++)
    {   for (j=0; j<c; j++)
        {   if (comp[i].num_compte==&n)
            {   if (comp[j].num_compte==&m)
                {   if(comp[n].solde>s) {
                        comp[i].solde-=s;
                        comp[j].solde+=s;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Guys Sorry i will add here this maybe it will make a diffrent ...

```
 typedef struct {
char *nom;
char *prenom;
long *num_compte;
float *solde;
}compte;


compte comp[50];
    int c=0;
```

Comment: What's `comp[i].num_compte`?

Comment: Problem is in this line `comp[j].solde+=s;`

Comment: Also, `scanf("%d",&n);` is wrong, you should use `%ld`.

Comment: scanf("%i",&s); scans an int and puts it into a float variable???

Comment: Also, you have not declared all the variables in the loops.

Comment: The error message should tell you which line is faulty. (It'll have a line number).  Also: I suggest you learn how to format code to make it easy to read - someone's reformatted your question for you.  Also, try to make a minimal example that reproduces the error, by deleting bits and seeing if you still get the same error - this will help you track down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to add a pointer to a floating point number.

However in this case the declaration is wrong and it should be "float s;" instead of "float *s;" In addition, correct "*s/=4.0;" to "s/=4.0;".

Answer (score 1):

The variable s is a pointer to a float. It's not a float. To get the value that is being pointed to, you need to use *s like this: comp[j].solde+=*s;

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have

```
float *s;
scanf("%i",&s);
```

and you try

```
*s/=4.0;
```

You'll probably get a SIGSEGV for that because you are allocating the address given by the user to `s`, which will almost surely result in a Segmentation Fault.

Also, you are trying

```
comp[j].solde+=s;
```

and `s` is a pointer, so you are trying to add the address of `s` to it ( no idea why you are doing that ) .

So, I suggest you change `s` from a pointer to a normal float

```
float s;
```

Comment: i'm new so i make really weiird mistakes , thaanks for ur help but i do what u said i have the same error !

Comment: @YahyaOweis That's probably because you are using pointers the wrong way ( do you need pointers in your struct, if not then change `float *solde;` to `float solde;` )

Comment: I will read about pointers now to understand more , thaanks for u time that was really nice from you